# EJS client side variables undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, server-side-rendering

Here is my very code which I got from the example in the EJS readme:

```
<div id="output"></div>
<script src="/js/ejs.min.js"></script>
<script>
  html = ejs.render('<%= people %>', {people: 'hello'});
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = html;
</script>
```

With just that basic code, I'm getting an error somehow,

```
ReferenceError: /Users/owner/Dropbox/answered-client/views/pages/test.ejs:4
    2| <script src="/js/ejs.min.js"></script>
    3| <script>
 >> 4|   html = ejs.render('<%= people %>', {people: 'hello'});
    5|   document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = html;
    6| </script>
    7| 

    people is not defined
        at eval (eval at compile (/Users/owner/Dropbox/answered-client/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:549:12), <anonymous>:11:26)
        at returnedFn (/Users/owner/Dropbox/answered-client/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:580:17)
        at tryHandleCache (/Users/owner/Dropbox/answered-client/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:223:34)
        at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/Users/owner/Dropbox/answered-client/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:437:10)
        at View.render (/Users/owner/Dropbox/answered-client/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
        at tryRender (/Users/owner/Dropbox/answered-client/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
        at Function.render (/Users/owner/Dropbox/answered-client/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
        at ServerResponse.render (/Users/owner/Dropbox/answered-client/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1008:7)
        at app.get (/Users/owner/Dropbox/answered-client/index.js:36:7)
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/owner/Dropbox/answered-client/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty late here, but I just solved this problem myself. The problem is that the EJS you want rendered by the client is in a .ejs file that's first being parsed by the server, so the server is the one that's throwing the error because it isn't reading your JS to know what `people` is.

The quick fix to this was to put the code that's rendering the client side EJS in an external .js file and include it. But I believe you can also use `ejs.delimiter` property to change the tags from `<% %>` to something like `<? ?>`, and this way, that section of code won't get parsed by the server.

Comment: I knew what the problem was, but only found the solution here. Great answer, can recommend doing it with delimiters, no need to add extra files.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass it under locals as follows

```html
<div id="output"></div>
<script src="/js/ejs.min.js"></script>
<script>
  html = ejs.render('<%= people %>', { locals: {people: 'hello'}}); // locals
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = html;
</script>
```